# How do I call managed .NET code from my un-managed C++ code in Windows and vice versa?

Tags: .net, c++, pinvoke, unmanaged, managed

I have a pure C++ application developed using VC 6.0. I would like this application to make use of a library developed in C#. How do I call the methods in the C# library from my native executable? I do not want to convert my un-managed C++ native application to managed code. Similarly, how do I do the reverse? Is PInvoke the only option? I would appreciate any references or pointers for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call into managed code from unmanaged C++, use [ClrCreateManagedInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230997.aspx), or export your types in your managed assembly as COM visible, and use COM. To call into unmanaged code from managed, use COM or P/Invoke.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's main line on this is use COM interop. There is however another option, sometimes referred to as "Reverse P/Invoke" there is a interesting blog post [here](http://tigerang.blogspot.com/2008/09/reverse-pinvoke.html) and some more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx)

Also, if you have Delphi.NET (now defunct) this language allows you to export static methods like you would any dll function then you can call into the Delphi.NET assembly just like a normal native Dll.